# Conditional rendering through multidimensional loop with array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem in rendering through loop with multidimensional array. I have 4 div as column and I need to put images (provided in array) on it.

For the explanation you can check on the Images I attach. (below the link)

[image: image link]

I've tried a lot of time using my code and ended up stuck on this code.

```
    let temp=[];

    for(let i=0;i<4;i++){
        temp.push(
          <div className="imagesColumn">
                {
                    this.state.images.map((item,index) => {
                        return(
                           <img key={index} src={item.urlImages} width="100%"/>
                        )   

                    })
                }
          </div>
        )
    }
```

As you see on my code above, what I want is, the first loop is to make the 4 column div and the second loop is to put in the images.

I've failed to make it happen like in the image I gave, because every image got loop 4 times based on first loop.

How can I do that? Anyone can help and give a code example please

Comment: Sorry I was just make it more clear on the images and It's my latest edit

Comment: I understood. I did made it better again. Don't worry. Check out my answer... 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are currently doing is, you are pushing 6 images in your state to each of your `<div>`, and HTML / React JS doesn't work this way. What you may do is to do a calculative push for each column. So that, first column contains 4n + 1 image, second column with 4n + 2 image and so on.

This way, we can avoid using a `temp` variable.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    images: ["Image 1", "Image 2", "Image 3", "Image 4", "Image 5", "Image 6"]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {[1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => (
          <div className="col">
            {this.state.images.map((f, i) =>
              4 * i + n - 1 < this.state.images.length ? (
                <div className="img">{this.state.images[4 * i + n - 1]}</div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Snippet**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    images: ["Image 1", "Image 2", "Image 3", "Image 4", "Image 5", "Image 6"]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {[1, 2, 3, 4].map(n => (
          <div className="col">
            {this.state.images.map((f, i) =>
              4 * i + n - 1 < this.state.images.length ? (
                <div className="img">{this.state.images[4 * i + n - 1]}</div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  line-height: 1;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.img {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> **Note:** You might just need to change it to images.

Here's a demo in [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2krw7lj67).

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Explanation**

The condition is as follows:

```
4 x imageIndex + columnNumber, where imageIndex is less than length of list of images.
```

So, in theory, when we try to loop on the column number, i.e., `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, what we get is:

```
Col = 1
ImageIndex = 0
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 0)
ImageIndex = 4
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 4)

Col = 2
ImageIndex = 1
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 1)
ImageIndex = 5
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 5)

Col = 3
ImageIndex = 2
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 2)

Col = 4
ImageIndex = 3
Image (4 * i + n - 1 = 3)
```

The other places in the loop will not be rendering as they don't meet the condition.

Comment: What do you mean by 4n? I still don't understand sorry

Comment: @Billy `4n` is because you have 4 columns and `n` gets incremented each time. In your first column, you have image 1 and image 5. In your second column, you have image 2 and image 6 and so on. So if you replace `n` with `0` and `1` for now, what you get is Image 1 and Image 5 for `n = 1` and Image 2 and Image 6 for `n = 2`. If you didn't understand this explanation, I am happy to write more in the answer. 

Comment: Excellent answer Praveen! :) . Thank u so much for making the solution for me . I'll surely will learn and understand the code and explanation you gave! 

Comment: @Billy Anytime mate. Let me know if you need more help. I am a React JS mentor and I would love to help you with learning React! 